# Updating SQL database Issue

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

Thanks so much for your response. So I've made the changes you suggested, but i'm still not getting my database to update.  The only thing that I have changed from your code is the MessageBox lines. I changed those to Alert messages. What am I missing here?  Maybe my variables need to be declared differently Thanks!!!

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim x As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim r As Integer

    Dim V1 As String
    Dim V2 As String




    x = txbPalletNumber.Text
    z = txbOrderNumber.Text
    r = txbShipmentNumber.Text


    Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Traceability\Traceability.accdb")
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbPalletNumber.Text, x) Then
                Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""Pallet Number must be a Number"");</script")
                Exit Sub
                End If
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbOrderNumber.Text, z) Then
                Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""Order Number must be a Number"");</script")
                Exit Sub
                End If
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbShipmentNumber.Text, r) Then
                Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""Shipment Number must be a Number"");</script")
                Exit Sub
                End If
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = @x ", conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                    conn.Open()
                    V1 = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                conn.Close()

            End Using
                If V1 = "In Stock" Then
                    Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = @z, ShipmentNumber = @r WHERE PalletNumber = @x", conn)
                        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = @z, ShipmentNumber = @r WHERE PalletNumber = @x "
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@z", OleDbType.Integer).Value = z
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@r", OleDbType.Integer).Value = r
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                    Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = @x", conn)
                        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                        conn.Open()
                        V2 = CStr(cmd3.ExecuteScalar())
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                    Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Status to " & x & " has Changed to " & V2 & """);</script")
                Else
                    Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Pallet is not In Stock to Ship"");</script")
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error handling
        End Try

        txbSearch.Text = txbPalletNumber.Text
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Explain what isn't working,  specifically.

Comment: My Update statement isnt updating the database.@brien

Comment: Except that I'm seeing the alert message "The Status to x has Changed to V2", so it has to running the Update SQL. But for some reason its not updating.@brien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite the value of your commandtext with a select statement before executing the update statement, so it is never run.

Comment: THANKS!!! okay so how do i fix this?@Kyle Burns

Answer (score 0):

You can declare new oledbcommand since the last command overwrite the update command:

`Dim cmd2 as New OleDbCommand
'Set the command properties.
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = " & x & " "
    V1 = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If V1 = "In Stock" Then
        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = " & z & ", ShipmentNumber = " & r & " WHERE PalletNumber = " & x & " "
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = " & x & " "
        V2 = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Status to " & x & " has Changed to " & V2 & """);</script")
    Else
        Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Pallet is not In Stock to Ship"");</script")
        End If
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()`

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Option Strict now and for all your projects. Open your connection directly before your execute and close it immediately after. Check with TryParse that you have the correct numeric input. Use Parameters always. It will curtail the disastrous SQL injection and make your SQL statements easier to write. I have added Using..End Using statements. This will take care of Disposing your objects. It will also close your connection if an error occurs before a .Close() method is reached. I would have liked to reuse the x parameter but Access does not care about parameter names, only the order in the SQL statement so I used a new command each time. I have showed how to use Constructors to save a few lines of code; passing the connection string in the connection constructor and passing the CommandText and the Connection directly to the Command construtor. It appeared from your SQL statements, that x, z, and r are all numeric types not strings so I guessed at Integer. You may have to change this, depending on the datatype in the table.

```
Dim x As Integer
        Dim z As Integer
        Dim r As Integer
        Dim V1 As String
        Dim V2 As String
        Try
            Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Traceability\Traceability.accdb")
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbPalletNumber.Text, x) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the Pallet.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbOrderNumber.Text, z) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the Order Number.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                If Not Integer.TryParse(txbShipmentNumber.Text, r) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the Shipment Number.")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = @x ", conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                    conn.Open()
                    V1 = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                    conn.Close()
                End Using
                If V1 = "In Stock" Then
                    Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = @z, ShipmentNumber = @r WHERE PalletNumber = @x", conn)
                        cmd2.CommandText = "UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = @z, ShipmentNumber = @r WHERE PalletNumber = @x "
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@z", OleDbType.Integer).Value = z
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@r", OleDbType.Integer).Value = r
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                    Using cmd3 As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = @x", conn)
                        cmd3.Parameters.Add("@x", OleDbType.Integer).Value = x
                        conn.Open()
                        V2 = CStr(cmd3.ExecuteScalar())
                        conn.Close()
                    End Using
                    Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Status to " & x & " has Changed to " & V2 & """);</script")
                Else
                    Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">alert(""The Pallet is not In Stock to Ship"");</script")
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error handling
        End Try
```

Comment: can you look at my original post up top? Ive made all your changes but still not working. @Mary

Comment: Well, I tried similar on a Access db that I have and it worked. Sometimes data files are copied to a local directory and it is updating the wrong file. Change the line cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() to Dim RowsAffected as Integer = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()  Then Display RowsAffected. I would do Debug.Print(RowsAffected.ToString) you might have to imports System.Diagnostics. RowsAffected should be 1.

Comment: Thanks for this Mary, I actually got it working a different way, now I'm running into this issue. https://forums.asp.net/p/2138477/6199292.aspx?Need+Help+with+SQL+Update+Parameters+ @Mary

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn coding standard first, declaring variables like x,y,z, I haven't seen from quite long time.

You are overwriting cmd.CommandText

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = " & z & ", ShipmentNumber = " & r & " WHERE PalletNumber = " & x & " "
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Status FROM tblPalletRecords WHERE Palletnumber = " & x & " "
            V2 = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

To Fix:

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblPalletRecords SET OrderNumber = " & z & ", ShipmentNumber = " & r & " WHERE PalletNumber = " & x & " "
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Using parameters would be better to help stop sql injection.

Comment: True! That's what I mentioned in first line bad coding standards! :)